# How to reference different wallets with curl JSONRPC requests Bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, json-rpc, wallet.dat

I have a headless Bitcoin core 0.17.1 running on Debian 10, and have created a second wallet "johns-wallet".

I'd like to get the walletinfo (or any wallet request) of that specific wallet via curl, not the cli.

[The Bitcoin core API reference](https://bitcoin-rpc.github.io/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/getwalletinfo/) doesn't offer an example of how to target different wallets when not using the CLI (and neither did my Google search).

I've tried:

```
curl --user johnsmith --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getwalletinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' bitcoind:18332/wallets/johns-wallet/
```

and also

```
curl --user johnsmith --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getwalletinfo", "params": ["/wallets/johns-wallet/"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' bitcoind:18332
```

And also variations on the path itself to the wallet - none of them return a result, let alone an error.

Running without trying to specify a wallet returns:

```
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-19,"message":"Wallet file not specified (must request wallet RPC through /wallet/<filename> uri-path)."},"id":"curltest"}
```

(In case it matters, the Bitcoind is running in a docker container, with a named volume)

Comment: Off the top of my head, the path needs to match the wallet path relative to your datadir - so `bitcoind:8332/wallets/john` only works if your wallets are actually in `$datadir/wallets/`. I might be wrong on this though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the command I use - the http address is the address of the docker container that the Bitcoin daemon is running in

```
curl --user johnsmith --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getbalance", "params": ["*", 6] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://10.0.0.1:18332/
```